# OpenVPN error : Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a ovpn file with following format.

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote MY_IP 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
ns-cert-type server
key-direction 1 
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 1
mute 20

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
M---DeletedContent
+Jl7
-----END CERTIFICATE-----


-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
DeletedContentYsuN5d
-----END CERTIFICATE-----


-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,EB9C4DDDD26848F5

PDeletedContent
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----


#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
DeletedContent
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
```

When I am trying to open this with OVPN 2.4.4 getting following error:

> Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in C:\Users\Stevens\Desktop\user01.ovpn:17: ---BEGIN (2.4.4)
>   Use --help for more information.
>   Press any key to continue...

Line 17 is the 1st -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap your certs in suitable block directives, my similar file has this structure

```
...
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
....
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
...
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Comment: Thanks very much , It just saved lot of myday. Now getting  errors , Fri Dec 15 08:57:26 2017 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Fri Dec 15 08:57:26 2017 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Fri Dec 15 08:57:31 2017 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
Fri Dec 15 08:57:31 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]MY_IP:1194
Fri Dec 15 08:57:31 2017 UDP link local: (not bound)
Fri Dec 15 08:57:31 2017 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]155.143.41.148:1194
Fri Dec 15 08:57:31 2017 read UDP: Unknown error (code=10054)